# How to text cell phones from Matlab?

Tags: matlab, sms, sendmail

I have a Matlab program that runs daily from Windows Task Scheduler. The program output is a decision whether a machine needs monitoring or not. I'd like to text this information to some coworkers's cell phones.  I know Matlab's sendmail program can be used to text a cell phone if you have the [phone number]@[carrier address], such as 1111111111@txt.att.net. However I am having trouble with the authentications required by the different carriers. Since I can call/text their cell phone without having to supply authentication information, there must be an easier way to text the information. Do you have any suggestions?  A non-Matlab solution would be fine, for example I could save the message text to an ASCII file that the outside program then reads and texts to the phones. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Not strictly speaking an answer to your particular problem, but there is a tool on the Matlab File Exchange that does this by using a google calendar ([this page](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25698-create-google-calendar-event-with-sms-and-email-notification)). Maybe you can tweak it to your needs.

Comment: Good suggestion - I had success with another File Exchange submission. I used another programmer's authentication approach [(this page)](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16649-send-text-message-to-cell-phone/content/send_text_message.m) plus sendmail. It sends emails from a Gmail account. Somehow that gets past the permissions required to text to an AT&T phone, plus yahoo and hotmail email accounts and my work email.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you in the US?

If so, this will work:
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16649

Comment: Yes, it will work nicely...as long as the internet preferences are set up correctly to be able to send to the various carriers. Sending the texts from my Gmail account using the permissions described [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16649-send-text-message-to-cell-phone/content/send_text_message.m) worked but any other account (including my work email) didn't.